# Rails server startup error after project creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to learn Ruby on rails and I create a new project and when I try to start the server wit `rails server` I get this error.

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.6 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
/home/andrei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/home/andrei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
Exiting
Traceback (most recent call last):
    4222: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    4221: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    4220: from /home/andrei/Projects/Ruby/blog/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    4219: from /home/andrei/Projects/Ruby/blog/bin/spring:15:in `require'
    4218: from /home/andrei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    4217: from /home/andrei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
    4216: from /home/andrei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    4215: from /home/andrei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
     ... 4210 levels...
       4: from /home/andrei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
       3: from /home/andrei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
       2: from /home/andrei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
       1: from /home/andrei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
/home/andrei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
```

Comment: Try [googling](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&hs=4w3&channel=fs&q=rails+4.2.6+Fixnum+is+deprecated&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjArKDx_IDZAhVEwmMKHSb9CE0QBQgkKAA&biw=1273&bih=922). Second hit. Your version of rails may not be compatible with your version of ruby.

Comment: I recommend rails 5.0 and ruby 2.3.3. That's enough for you to learn ruby on rails. Take a look on this http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to update Rails to a newer version.  I believe 5.1.4 is the most up-to-date.  I know there are a lot of compatibility issues with Rails 4.2 and any Ruby version above 2.4, as seen in [**this**](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/27670) question and many other queries online.

Try running `bundle install` while in the Rails application.